# Is bool data type supported in embedded C?

Tags: c, embedded, avr, avrdude, mcu

The wrote the following code for avr MCU and I compiled and uploaded the code with Arduino IDE, I did not get any error and the code works but I remembered C program does not support bool data type. Will this code still be compiled  with avr-gcc on Linux.

````
//The following code is written for ATmega328P microcontroller
// Turns ON the led on a click of a switch and Turns OFF it again another click
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>


#define LED_PIN   PB5
#define SW_PIN    PD2


volatile bool ledOn = false;


// Function to initialize pinmode and interrupt
void init() {
 // Set LED pin as output
  DDRB = DDRB |(1 << DDB5);
  // Set switch pin as  pull-up resistor
  PORTD = PORTD |(1 << SW_PIN);
  // Enable interrupt on the switch pin
  EIMSK = EIMSK |(1 << INT0);
  // Trigger interrupt on failing edge of the switch signal
  EICRA = (1 << ISC01);
  // Enable global interrupts
  sei();
}


// Interrupt service routine for the switch
ISR(INT0_vect) {
  // If the switch is pressed, toggle the LED state
  if ((~PIND & (1 << SW_PIN)) && !ledOn) {
   PORTB = PORTB | (1 << LED_PIN);
    ledOn = true;
  }
  else{
  PORTB = PORTB & ~(1 << LED_PIN);
    ledOn = false;
  }

}

int main(void) {
 // Initialization
  init();

 // Loop forever
 while (1) {

    // NOP
  }

  return 0;
}```
````

Comment: `bool` support is not a function of the hardware but of the compiler. Nevertheless, you should include `<stdbool.h>`

Comment: The standard C spelling for the data type is `_Bool`.  However, standard C does not define any corresponding constants, so if you also want `false` and `true` to be defined for you (instead of simply using 0 and 1, respectively) then `stdbool.h` will get you those, plus a typedef for `bool`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger `bool` is a preprocessor macro not a typedef.

Comment: You are correct, @TomV, I misspoke.  However, the situations in which the difference would be important are rare.

Comment: Arduino is very likely using C++. Step 1: find out what compiler you are actually using.

Comment: @JohnBollinger C23 will actually promote them to proper keywords. The macros with the same names will be deprecated, as will stdbool.h. However, I doubt the OP is using C23 but instead they are very likely using a C++ compiler.

Comment: @hcheung Avr-libc has nothing to do with _recognition_ of `bool`. It's the compiler by its language with C++ or the inclusion of "stdbool.h" with C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Arduino IDE uses C++ compilation - you are using C++ not C - even if it is otherwise valid C code, and you are not using the Arduino `setup()`/`loop()` framework or Arduino libraries..

With respect to C however, C99 defines a built-in type `_Bool`.  It does that because of all the pre-C99 code that exists that might define types or macro aliases for Boolean in various ways. It prevents breaking existing code that the introduction of a new keywords `bool`, `true` and `false` might otherwise cause.

C99 also defines a header stdbool.h which provides a C++-like `bool` alias for `_Bool`, and symbols for `true` and `false` values.  Including stdbool.h or cstdbool in C++ code has no effect.

The Arduino compiler is the same AVR GCC cross-compiler you are proposing to use on linux.  It supports both C and C++ compilation.  You can use the avr-g++ driver for C++ compilation, but its only difference to the avr-gcc driver is that it links C++ library support implicitly when invoking ld.  Otherwise C or C++ compilation is determined by command line switch or by source file extension.

So your code will compile as-is with AVR GCC if you use the same C++ compilation that Arduino applies, but if you want to ensure it builds with either C or C++ compilation (or you just want to make it valid C code) you can simply add `#include <stdbool.h>` and it will work in either case.

Answer (score 3):

> Will this code still be compiled with avr-gcc on Linux

I kind of doubt you will be able to run Linux on an AVR :)

But no it will not compile with gcc under Linux since it is invalid C. From C99 to C17 versions of the standard you need to `#include <stdbool.h>` to use `bool`. C uses the keyword `_Bool` and `bool` from `stdbool.h` is just a macro for that.

Upcoming C23 will remove all this nonsense and then `bool`, `true` and `false` will become proper language keywords. So it will actually compile on Linux if you use "gcc trunk" version and compile with `-std=c2x`, which is about to be formally released as gcc 13 `-std=c23` later this year.

The reason why it compiles on your Arduino is because you are using a C++ compiler. That's a different programming language.

Comment: thank you and i know i wont be able to run linux on ATmega328p.I meant will it be compiled on linux using avr-gcc, with which we compile c for avr

Comment: @JagMohanRay Which host OS it runs on doesn't matter for a cross-compiler.

Comment: _I kind of doubt you will be able to run Linux on an AVR :)_ as far as I know [it has been done before](https://hackaday.com/2012/03/28/building-the-worst-linux-pc-ever/) (doesn't mean you should)